# Setting up a linux web server using a static IP in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, webserver

I am new in setting up a new web server.

I am attempting to set up a static web server using Ubuntu 16.04 running on an iMac.

I have already configured the static IP in the device and can access it locally. However, when I try to visit the static IP from another device, the web browser always outputs an error (Site cannot be reached)

this is my Interfaces file

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
#CK: Delete this line and uncomment lines inside if not working.
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
#CK: Delete this line and uncomment lines inside if not working.
#auto wlp2s0
#iface wlp2s0 inet static
auto enp3s0f0
iface enp3s0f0 inet static
address 121.58.252.189
netmask 255.255.255.240
gateway 121.58.252.177
dns-nameservers 121.58.250.195 202.58.250.195
```

How can I set up a port to access my web server so I can try to forward the port on my router?

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
I am using Apache2 server

Comment: Which server you are using for hosting your files e.g Ngins, Apache, Http-server

Comment: Hi @SantoshSingh I am using Apache in hosting my files

Comment: The port depends on your server. Normal http traffic should run on port 80 while https should come in on 443. But first of all please add some information on which webserver you are running. Nginx, apache2 etc